# Deriving the Equation of a Light Body orbiting a Heavy Body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

If a light body orbits a heavy body, the orbit of the light body in classical mechanics is given by:

$$  \frac{d^2}{d \phi^2}  \bigg( \frac{1}{r(\phi)} \bigg)  + \frac{1}{r( \phi) } = \frac{GM}{h^2} \ ,$$

where $M$ is the mass of the heavy body and $h$ is a constant related to the angular velocity of the light body.

What is the derivation for this equation, or is there a reference where it can be found?

Comment: This is in basically all the good mechanics texts, because it is the way from N2L to the ellipse solution. You use the conservation of angular momentum and energy to eliminate time dependence from the radial equation, leaving you with a complicated equation that is the same as this equation, upon expanding the derivative on this equation. The $u=1/r$ trick is very famous for this particular problem.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem#Solution_of_the_Kepler_problem)

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of
motion of two masses  is described by Newton’s second law of motion
\begin{align*}
  &m\,\ddot{\vec{r}}=\vec f\tag 1
\end{align*}

where $~\vec f~$ is the attracting force, and $~\vec{r}~$ is the distance between the two masses

\begin{align*}
  &\vec f(r)=\frac{G\,M\,m}{r^2}\frac{\vec r}{| \vec r|}
\end{align*}

thus equation (1)

\begin{align*}
  &\ddot{\vec{r}}=\frac{G\,M}{r^2}\frac{\vec r}{| \vec r|}
\end{align*}

with $~\vec{r}~$ is given  with  polar coordinate
\begin{align*}
  &\vec r=r\,\begin{bmatrix}
               \cos(\theta) \\
               \sin(\theta) \\
             \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
you obtain two differential equations
\begin{align*}
&\ddot r- r\dot \theta^2=-\frac{G\,M}{r^2}\tag 2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&{r^2\ddot \theta+r\,2\dot r\dot \theta}=0\quad,
\frac{d}{dt}\left(r^2\,\dot{\theta}\right)=0,\quad\Rightarrow~
r^2\dot\theta=h\\& \frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{h}{r^2}
 \end{align*}

how to solve equation (2). we want to find the solution $~r=r(\theta)~$

with $~r(\theta)=\frac{1}{u(\theta)}~$

\begin{align*}
 &\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{d\theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt} =
 \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)\,h\,u^2=-h\,\frac{du}{d\theta}\\
 &\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dr}{dt}\right)=-h\,\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}\frac{d\theta}{dt}
 =-h^2\,u^2\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}\quad\Rightarrow
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 &\ddot r- r\dot \theta^2=-\frac{G\,M}{r^2}\mapsto\\
 &\boxed{\,\frac{d^2 u}{d\theta^2}+u=\frac{G\,M}{h^2}\,}
\end{align*}

and the solution is:

\begin{align*}
&u(\theta)=d_1\cos(\theta)+d_2\sin(\theta)+\frac{G\,M}{h^2}
\end{align*}

where $~d_1~,d_2~$ are integration constants